# compilation error for custom generic class

Tags: java, string, generics

I came across this code

```
class Test<String> {
    String my = "Hello!"; //--- 1
    String s = new String("aaa"); //---- 2
}
```

The code give 2 compile time errors: 
for 1. add a cast to String
for 2. cannot instantiate string

Why so?

```
List <? extends String(or any random class)> = new ArrayList<Anyclass>();
```

What is the reason that this code compiles?

Comment: In this case, `String` is the name of your generic, and you hide the `java.lang.String` class. I would recommend using a totally different name for your generic.

Answer (score 2):

By using `Test<String>` you are declaring your own custom type which hides `java.lang.String` Use

```
class Test<T> {
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a generic type parameter for your generic class, don't use an existing class name (such as String).

If you would use a more traditional parameter name, T, the errors you got would be more clear :

```
T my = "Hello!"; // doesn't compile since T can be anything, not necessarily a String
T s = new T("aaa"); // doesn't compile since Java does not allow you to call a constructor of 
                    // a generic type parameter (new T() wouldn't work either), and you don't
                    // even know whether the class used as the actual parameter when you instantiate
                    // your generic class would even have a constructor that accepts a String
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a generic type parameter called `String` which is different from a normal reference to the built-in `String` class.  So the type of `my` and `s` are your type parameter, not the built-in `String`, so they aren't compatible.

Remove the `String` generic type parameter from your `Test` class; it's useless.

```
class Test {
```

This line doesn't compile, because `Anyclass` doesn't extend `String` (and it can't; `String` is `final`.

```
List <? extends String> x = new ArrayList<Anyclass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generic type `class Test<String>` doesn't represent `java.lang.String`. What happens here is that you are setting name of generic type to `String`, not its value.

In other words your code can be rewritten to

```
class Test<T> {
    T my = "Hello!"; //--- 1
    T s = new T("aaa"); //---- 2
}
```

so compiler can't safely assume that `T` is in fact `String` so it prevents you from initializing variables of type `T` with `instances of Stirng` type.

---

> What is the reason that this code compiles?

```
List <? extends String(or any random class)> = new ArrayList<Anyclass>();
```

Well, here you are not deciding how generic type should be named, but what value should it represent. `<? extends String>` represent type which is `java.lang.String` or derived from it (which in this case will not happen because String is final class).